# Can I re-run SharePoint 2010 SP2 with no issues?

Tags: psconfig

I was installing SharePoint 2010 SP2, and the installation of the binaries completed, however, I ran into an error when running the PSCONFIG part of it.

I restarted the computer and re-ran the PSCONFIG, and it seemed like it "fixed" the issue, since the next time I ran PSCONFIG it didn't give me an error. However, I've discovered some error logs that indicate that the PSCONFIG part of the SP2 update wasn't installed properly (errors connecting to DB, etc.) plus SHarePoint 2010 thinks my server needs an update.

How can I manually re-run the PSCONFIG part of the 2010 SP2 install?

Answer (score 0):

Just run the Products and Configuration Wizard again. For what it's worth, sometimes the psconfig does fail the first time. I always have a rule of thumb to run it twice if it fails before freaking out. Make sure that the patch has been installed on every server before you start the Products and Config Wizard (one at a time) on each server.

If you wanted to run the psconfig from the command line you can use the following line when opening the SharePoint Management Shell:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```